# Trying to change add method to work as a button

Tags: java, user-interface, generics, button, tree

I'm trying to make this code work as an add button instead of just pressing enter with a text field.

```
  ActionListener cmdLis = new CmdTextListener();

     cmdTextField.addActionListener(cmdLis);

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
             {
               String cmdStr = cmdTextField.getText();
               Scanner sc = new Scanner(cmdStr);
               String cmd = sc.next();

if (cmd.equals("add"))
               {
                   int value = sc.nextInt();
                   binTree.add(value);

                   if(view != null)
                       remove(view);
                   view = binTree.getView();
                   add(view);

                   pack();
                   validate();
                   cmdResultTextField.setText(" ");

               }
```

So i tried to do it like this but its doing nothing when i push the button its not even picking up the button push

```
  if (e.getSource() == addButton)
               {
                   //int value = Integer.parseInt(cmd);

                   int value = Integer.parseInt(cmdStr);
                   binTree.add(value);

                   if(view != null)
                       remove(view);
                   view = binTree.getView();
                   add(view);

                   pack();
                   validate();
                   cmdResultTextField.setText("Added "+ value);

               }
```

Comment: did you call `addButton.addActionListener(cmdLis);`

Comment: Please clarify your question and your code. I can't speak for others, but it isn't clear what you're trying to do or what that code does. Consider posting more detailed and clear explanation and better code, preferably a [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please read the link).

Comment: Thank you Guleryuz god i tried 10 different ways at least to add the action listeners and thats ALL i was missing

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use simple GUI instead of console to input some values. Your code is incomplete - it is not clear what exactly you would like to achieve but I made some example for you which can be helpful.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton button;

    // private YourBinaryTree;

    public Main() {

        textField = new JTextField(5);

        button = new JButton("add to binary tree");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String read = textField.getText();
                Integer number = Integer.parseInt(read);
                // binTree.add(number);
            }
        });

        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        getContentPane().add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```